# I have used structure to return multiple value.But I am not getting any result though the program runs

Tags: c

[main function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNQn0.png) [String lengthh function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8E5dN.png)

It runs but doesn't display any result.
What is the problem can any tell me.
And what to do to solve it

Comment: Thanks .Can you help me please to solve my problem.

Comment: You're not incrementing `i` or `j` in the loop. `i+1` will always just be `1`.

Comment: Also, your final `printf` doesn't have any place-holders (%d) for the int arguments.

Comment: Code needs to be included in the question _as text_, not an image.  See [ask].

Comment: Lee Daniel Crocker thanks.It worked.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is with operators.

When you count the length of each string, you assign `S.counter1` to `i+1`, however `i` stays the same each iteration of the for loop. The operator you'd want to use for this is `++`, the increment operator. It increments a variable by one.

Instead of `S.counter1=i+1;`, you should use `S.counter1=i++;`, which actually increments the counter. You could also use `S.counter1++;`, and just increment the counter directly instead of using a temporary variable. Note if you do this you'd have to use `S.counter1` as the index in the strings.

Also instead of writing your own loop to count the characters before a zero terminator, there exists a standard function to do the same thing, `strlen`. Include `<string.h>` and then you can use `strlen` to count each string.

Assign `S.counter1` to `strlen(a)` and the same for the second string and then you have much more readable code.

I'd also recommend padding operators and casts, e.g. instead of `i+1` you'd have `i + 1` and instead of `(char*)malloc(...)` you'd have `(char*) malloc(...)`. This is of course personal preference.